# How to transfer symbolic expression to code?

Tags: symbolic, excel, excellink

I have a lot of messy things in *Mathematica* in a form like this:

[image]

*Mathematica* perfectly solves all these symbolic equations. But I'm in trouble when using Excel link with *Mathematica*. I really need to use *Mathematica*-defined symbolic formulas in Excel, so how can I transform from symbolic language to code?

Comment: Talk is cheap. Ars longa, vita brevis.

Comment: There is no difference between what you call symbolic language" and what you call "code" in _Mathematica_, so it is not clear what you are asking for. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "code"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods. The first is to use the 'InputForm' function on any of your symbolic expressions.

You could also, in the long run, try to use the defined functions in *Mathematica* for the symbols to begin with. In my experience, this is a more robust method. For example, the [image: formula] you posted can be represented with the `Sum` function. Putting the symbols into *Mathematica*'s Wolfram Documentation (available in the Help menu), will give you how Mathematica interprets these symbols. For example, searching the summation symbol yields the information at the following link: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/Sum.html

Comment: Thank you, InputForm makes big sense!

Comment: However, I'm still experiencing problems trying to transform symbolic expression I've posted above. It goes to alpha[x_,y_,N_]:=    Sum[Subscript[x, i] + Subscript[y, i], {i, 1, N}]
 and I'm using =EVAL("alpha",H3:H9,I3:I9,7) formula in excel.No good, formula is not recognised :(

Comment: @simusminus: The syntax of Mathematica is different from Excel, and so you cannot just copy and paste. This will be a more manual process, as I do not know of any tools that do this explicitly (although they might exist without my knowledge).